# RegEx: words with no subword

Tags: regex, javacc, dfa

I'm looking for a regex to make a DFA that has all words except one.

Alphabet = {x, y, z}
Words = all possible words except words containing xyz. Example:

Valid: xyyzx yyxzyxz yyzzx

Invalid: x**xyz**z yxz**xyz** **xyz**yxz

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the discard technique by using a regex like this:

```
[xyz]*xyz[xyz]*|([xyz]+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/sX8eC7/1)**

The idea behind this regex is to **match the invalid** data but to **capture the important** data.

[image]

The match information is:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [7-12]  `xyyzx`
MATCH 2
1.  [13-20] `yyxzyxz`
MATCH 3
1.  [21-26] `yyzzx`
```

As you can see, you have to grab the capturing group content to get the valid data.

The discard technique consists of discarding all the pattern form the left side of the regex separated by pipes (regex "or") but using capturing group in the rightest pattern. So, for this regex:

```
[xyz]*xyz[xyz]*|([xyz]+)
discard patt--^    ^--- keep this pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

Fun!

```
\b(?:(?!xyz)[xyz])+\b
```

Match, between word boundaries, a sequence of one or more of x, y, or z, none of which are start the sequence xyz.

(Tested with `perl -nE ' say for /(\b(?:(?!xyz)[xyz])+\b)/g '`.)

Comment: Hi, that workds, but is possible to convert it to JavaCC syntax like this `("b")? ("b")? ("a" ("a")? "b" ("b")?)* ("a")? ("a")?` Thanks.

Comment: @allnex If you want a solution for JavaCC, you might want to tag your question with `javacc`, to get the experts' attention.  I'm not familiar with JavaCC syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what should happen if the string xyz is present. Should a TokenManagerError be thrown or ParseException? Usually in JavaCC it is good practice to accept all input at the lexical level --i.e. to write a token manager that throws no exceptions.  So that's what I'll do.

```
TOKEN: { 
    < BAD : (["x","y","z"])* "xyz" (["x","y","z"])* >
    < GOOD: (["x","y","z"])+ >
    < OTHER: ~[] >
}

void start() : {}{ [<GOOD>] <EOF> }
```

Any file that contains the string "xyz" will result in a parse error. Any file that contains a character other than x, y, or z will result in a parse error. Any other file will parse without error.

Comment: I think that `+` could safely be a `*`. Then the body of start would be `<GOOD> <EOF>`.